# how do i set up a 'proxy service' that routes through different proxy servers

Tags: squid, proxy

I have a VPS set up as a proxy server with Squid Proxy.

Now what I want to do is, set up another proxy server on a different VPS- this VPS will have its own set of possible IPs to function as a proxy.

I want to be able to route to any one of the proxies...

For doings the above, do I need to write a script/library from scratch? Is there any existing library which allows easy configuration of Squid, and allows multi-server Squid setups to function? (I would prefer for the library to be in Java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use both proxies in load balancing mode or active-passive mode, you can install an HTTP load balancer like [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt). Haproxy will receive the traffic and forward it to the appropriate proxy server according to the configuration.